# How to Add Text on Calendar Select Date Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, calendar, storyboard

I have this project from github [1]. I have the calendar running inside my app already everything seems to be working but when I click on a date it doesn't do anything. So my broad question would be where do I have to go to include the code so that when I click on a date it takes me to another storyboard so I can insert text or images in that select date.

[1] https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar

Would it be in the AppDelegate.swift or ViewController.Swift or inside the CVCalendar Folder?

Answer (score 0):

CVCalendar comes with a class method called didSelectDayView. Put this block of code in the ViewController where you are running the calendar.

```
func didSelectDayView(dayView: DayView) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("yourNextViewControllerID", sender: self)
}
```